# How to generate HTML files depends on array length php

Tags: php, html, xml

How to generate HTML files depends on array length php

I have an XML file.

```
<books>
  <book x="1" y="2">
     <name x="5" y="12">Java</name>
     <author x="8" y="16">Rao</author>
   </book>
   <book x="12" y="20">
     <name x="5" y="12">Php</name>
     <author x="5" y="12">Naidu</author>
   </book>
   <book x="19" y="29">
     <name x="25" y="22">Xml</name>
     <author x="25" y="12">Gowda</author>
   </book>
</books>
```

I have converted it into array using php.

I have standard html files i.e template.

```
<body>
  <div id="books" style="float:right; position:absolute; left: 199px; top: 245px;">
    <div id="book" style="float:right; position:absolute; left: 199px; top: 245px;">
    <div id="name" style="float:right; position:absolute; left: 199px; top: 245px;"></div>
    <div id="author" style="float:right; position:absolute; left: 199px; top: 245px;"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Based on the array legth,  I need to generate those many html files with dynamic values inside the div which are present in array .
Here i need to generate 3 html files (because i have 3 book elements).How can i generate the html files by using array.

array is look like this:

```
Array
(
    [book] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Java
                    [author] => Rao
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [x] => 1
                            [y] => 2
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Php
                    [author] => Naidu
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [x] => 12
                            [y] => 20
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Xml
                    [author] => Gowda
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [x] => 19
                            [y] => 29
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: What does the PHP array look like? And please stop using inline CSS.

Comment: Your template contains `books` div and a `book` div inside. So it is template of the whole your xml structure? All books should be in your html template? Or html template is for one book and you need generated file for every book?

Comment: i need HTML template for every book. not hole page. In whole html page i need to show these links as a tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html template, use delimiters like real-template :

```
<body>
    <div id="books" style="float:right; position:absolute; left: 199px; top: 245px;">
        <div id="book" style="float:right; position:absolute; left: 199px; top: 245px;">
            <div id="name" style="float:right; position:absolute; left: 199px; top: 245px;">{name}</div>
            <div id="author" style="float:right; position:absolute; left: 199px; top: 245px;">{author}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

In the PHP-side, use regexp to replace data in your template :

```
        $html_template = file_get_contents('/path/to/your/html/template');

        foreach($books['book'] as $i => $book) {
            $file_name = "html_page_for_book_{$i}";
            $html_file = fopen($file_name,'w');

            $html_data = preg_replace(array('/{author}/','/{name}/'),array($book['author'],$book['name']),$html_template);
            fwrite($html_file,$html_data);

            fclose($html_file);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect that someone who can parse XML into an array would be able to do this too but here you go anyway:

```
<body>
    <div id="books" style="float:right; position:absolute; left: 199px; top: 245px;">
        <?php foreach($books as $book) : ?>
        <div id="book" style="float:right; position:absolute; left: <?php echo $book['@attributes']['x']; ?>px; top: <?php echo $book['@attributes']['y']; ?>px;">
            <div id="name" style="float:right; position:absolute; left: 199px; top: 245px;"><?php echo $book['name']; ?></div>
            <div id="author" style="float:right; position:absolute; left: 199px; top: 245px;"><?php echo $book['author']; ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

ED|IT
I added the x/y attributes for the book, im sure you can do the rest yourself

Comment: there are different attributes for authors inside a book

Comment: what do you expect to happen with the attributes?

Comment: i need to replace those attributes with left and top position in CSS